# How to scale docker containers with arguments

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, scale

i wrote a python script that just grabs stock data and takes a symbol as an argument in the CLI and can dockerize just fine, however how can i scale this to 100 or more containers that build and then run at the same time, each having unique arguments? Heres some psuedo-code that shows what im trying to accomplish:

```
For symbol in df_NYSE.iterrows():
    build image with unique name..ie grab-stock-price-AMD (if argument passed is "--symbol AMD")
    store each image name in a list
    start each image in the list with the symbol variable in this for loop
```

Is this a task for kubernetes?

Comment: There's a lovely Python module for interacting with Docker; you can probably get from your pseudocode to a working program without too many more lines of code. I don't think you need the first step ("build image ..."); you should be able to use the same image for all your containers and pass in the configuration at runtime.

Comment: what module? docker-py?

Comment: Can you convert your script to a Python module, and just make ordinary function calls, without involving Docker?  This seems like it'd be easier to build, test, and run.

Comment: not sure if its possible, i want to get realtime data for around 100-200 stocks realtime, so i thought it would be easier to dockerize it. perhaps its still possible to just run 100 instances of the script, but not sold its the best solution.